# How to start a wrapped activity object?

Tags: android, oop

I am building a full screen app in Android Studio.
My app code is constrained by the DRY and KIS principles.
I managed to get the full screen code comply to both in the starting activity.
However, I require a new Activity for some things and the new activity obviously is not full screen. I know how to start a new activity using Intent but this will not 
let me start it using a new activity under the constraints.

My idea to keep it DRY and Simple by creating an object of the new activity in the starting activity and wrap it (like Decorator pattern) and pass the wrapper to the intent. The wrapper would contain the code to ensure that activity is in full screen. The wrapper is necessary because of both principles. I also plan on having even more full screen activities, so it will be reused.

It turns out Intent cannot accept an Activity object at all.

My question is then: How can one start a new activity using an Activity object?
Or even any other way to do something similar but complying to both DRY and KIS?

Comment: You can not, or rather you ***must not*** create an instance of an activity. The system manages the lifecycle of these special classes

Comment: With my limited knowledge of Android, that would imply it is impossible. Creating a new class somehow wraps another activity class cannot be DRY due to how static works. Reflection is also out of the question as well as Global variables, these would violate KIS.

Comment: you throw around a lot of buzzwords but honestly I have no clue what you're saying

Comment: Ah okay thanks for the heads up. Does that include the question itself? DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself principle, KIS = Keep it simple principle. With wrapping I refer to an object A that contains an object B of the same type and simply alters the behaviour of B somewhat. With static I refer to the Java keyword, static. Classes cannot be made into real object thus making it impossible to extend there behaviour (the static part of a class). Reflection is the technique where the code can read itself, as if it were the programmer.

Comment: erm yes I know what each of the words mean. I just can't make much sense of what you're saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the solution is indeed impossible to be DRY and Simple. 
An abstract 'FullscreenCompatActivity' class is to be inherited by activities that are fullscreen. They have to pass the root View and use setContent before doing so.
Though the inheritance keeps this DRY, it is not simple because specific calls are required.

Check the code out on:
https://github.com/ElwinBran/SuperclusterConflict